# Fill multidimensional maps in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to fill a multi-dimensional map in c++, and here is the code

```
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Vec3 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>;

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::pair<Vec3, std::vector<std::pair<Vec3, Vec3>>>>> test;
    Vec3 color = {255, 255, 0};
    std::vector<std::pair<Vec3, Vec3>> vector(2);
    std::map<std::string, std::pair<Vec3, std::vector<std::pair<Vec3, Vec3>>>>
        second;

    second["string1"] = std::make_pair(color, vector); // Works fine, just for testing
    // test["string2"] = std::make_pair("string1", std::make_pair(color, vector));  // Error
    test.insert(std::make_pair("string2", std::make_pair("string1", std::make_pair(color, vector)))); // error
}
```

Error -

```
<source>:19:40: error: no match for 'operator='
```

Here is the demo example - https://godbolt.org/z/a6EKjMPcf

**Edit - Found the solution**

```
test["string2"].insert(std::make_pair("string1", std::make_pair(color, vector)));
```

Comment: `test` is a `std::map<std::string, std::map<...>>`, why are you trying to store a `std::pair` in there?

Comment: @tkausl -   `test.insert(std::make_pair("string2", std::make_pair("string1", std::make_pair(color, vector))));` is also not working

This should create an element {key, value} of the map right ?

Comment: Of course this doesn't work either. Your value-type is __a map__ not a pair.

Comment: @tkausl Found the solution, have put it in the edits, thanks